# How change variables before rendering in phpfox?

Tags: phpfox

Hi I want to edit some variables before Phpfox rendering them into output without changing main files to keep theme updateable. For example I want to edit the value of location or birthday before they are rendered. What should I do exactly?

Comment: please provide a example so the we can understand easily

Answer (score 0):

The best way to make edits without disrupting any core files is with the use of plugin hooks. You could create your own module specifically for creating plugin files.

Here is a starter guide: http://phpfox.org/kb/article/144/creating-your-first-add-on/plugins/

Comment: The entirety of your answer depends on the contents of the link you gave. This won't be very helpful if that link no longer exists or becomes outdated. Please consider adding some relevant information with your answer to improve its quality.